# Clearing out a contentEditable div like you would an input with val('')?

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

Given an input type text, you can clear the input with `.val('')`.

How do you clear out a contentEditable element?

If I do:

```
$('#my_item').html('');
```

that clears out the p which I don't want.

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="my_item"><p>asdasddsa</p></div>
```

Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#my_item > p').html('');
```

This will clear all the content in your p tags in that editable region, but leave the p tags there